# how does JVM know the current method through PC

Tags: jvm

In 8086, we can know the next instruction to execute through CS:PC, where PC is the offset in the current code segement(CS).

However, I'm not sure how JVM knows which instruction to execute.

PC register in JVM only indicates the offset in the current method, but how does it know which method it's in?

Thanks!

I notice the codes for each method start from 0, like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqBbF.png)

So, if there are many methods in a class, how can I know which method the current frame is in?

I'm new to Java, so my question may be silly and my explaination is wrong. Thanks for bear with me!

Comment: You really brought the “*posting pictures of text instead of the text*” thing to a new level. Did you really print the text on paper, to post a photo of it here?

Comment: That picture comes from an article, and I just captured part of it. I think the picture is a scanned page of a book.

Comment: Well, that’s a typical output of the `javap` command which ships with every JDK. You can try, for example `javap -v -c java.lang.Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I assume that you are asking about the JVM in relation to the Java Virtual Machine Specification (JVMS).  The most directly relevant part of the spec says this:

> ### [2.5.1. The pc Register](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.1)
>
> The Java Virtual Machine can support many threads of execution at once
> (JLS §17). Each Java Virtual Machine thread has its own pc (program
> counter) register. At any point, each Java Virtual Machine thread is
> executing the code of a single method, namely the current method
> (§2.6) for that thread. **If that method is not native, the pc register
> contains the address of the Java Virtual Machine instruction currently
> being executed.** If the method currently being executed by the thread
> is native, the value of the Java Virtual Machine's pc register is
> undefined. The Java Virtual Machine's pc register is wide enough to
> hold a returnAddress or a native pointer on the specific platform.

Note the emphasized sentence.  It says the **address** of the instruction being executed.  It does not say the instruction's offset from the start of the method's code segment ... as you seem to be saying.

Furthermore, there is no obvious reference to a register holding a pointer to the current method.  And the section describing the call stack doesn't mention any pointer to the current method in the stack frame.

---

Having said all of that, the JVM specification is really a *behavioral* specification that JVM implementations need to conform to.  It doesn't directly mandate that the specified behavior must be implemented in any particular way.

So while it seems to state that the *abstract* JVM has a register called a PC that contains an "address", it doesn't state categorically what an address means in this context.  For instance, it does not preclude the possibility that the interpreter represents the "address" in the PC as a tuple consisting of a method address and a bytecode offset within the method.  Or something else.  All that really matters is that the JVM *implementation* can *somehow* use the PC to get the bytecode instruction to be executed.

Comment: The closest to a pointer to the current method is [the current stack frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se19/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6) which is typically referenced by a register.

Comment: Your answer really helps me! I ignored what JVM specification means and caught up into this silly question.  Thanks !!